# I am trying this QUERY, and return this weird error,please help me

Tags: mysql

```
select tbl_c_food_veg.pk_veg_id,tbl_c_food_veg.var_desc,tbl_c_food_veg.var_title ,tbl_c_food_veg_img.var_img,( select tbl_c_food_non_veg.pk_non_veg_id,tbl_c_food_non_veg.var_desc,tbl_c_food_non_veg.var_title,tbl_c_food_non_veg_img.var_img from tbl_c_food_non_veg left join tbl_c_food_non_veg_img on tbl_c_food_non_veg.pk_non_veg_id=tbl_c_food_non_veg_img.fk_non_veg_id where 

tbl_c_food_non_veg.fk_cat_id=8 and tbl_c_food_non_veg.pk_non_veg_id!=0  group by tbl_c_food_non_veg_img.fk_non_veg_id  order by tbl_c_food_non_veg.pk_non_veg_id desc limit 2 ) as non_veg,( select tbl_c_food_drinks.pk_drinks_id, tbl_c_food_drinks.var_desc, tbl_c_food_drinks.var_title, tbl_c_food_drinks_img.var_img from tbl_c_food_drinks left join tbl_c_food_drinks_img on tbl_c_food_drinks.pk_drinks_id=tbl_c_food_drinks_img .fk_drinks_id where 

tbl_c_food_drinks.fk_cat_id=8 and tbl_c_food_drinks.pk_drinks_id!=0  group by tbl_c_food_drinks_img.fk_drinks_id  order by tbl_c_food_drinks.pk_drinks_id desc limit 2 ) as drinks from  tbl_c_food_veg left join tbl_c_food_veg_img on tbl_c_food_veg.pk_veg_id=tbl_c_food_veg_img.fk_veg_id where 

tbl_c_food_veg.fk_cat_id=8 and tbl_c_food_veg.pk_veg_id!=0  group by tbl_c_food_veg_img.fk_veg_id  order by tbl_c_food_veg.pk_veg_id desc limit 2
```

Comment: and what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: consider using aliases for the tables; instead of writing `select aBigTableName.aField from aBigTableName` you can write `select a.aField from aBigTableName as a`. At the very least will make your sql instruction easier to read

Answer (score 0):

In your nested sub queries for retrieving non_veg and drinks you use limit 2 so most likely the subquery will return 2 rows, but you can only use one row. Change the limit to `limit 1`

and try using aliases as Barranka says it wil be much easier to read your query